# React tinymce paste original url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I'm using TinyMce editor (4.1.0) in my react project, and I am struggling with a problem: when I paste some url copied in the clipboard, the editor replaces the url I want to paste with the title of the page of the url.
How can I solve this? I managed to paste the url as plain text, but I want the text to be the url itself.

I noticed that this bug only appears when I copy the url from the browser search bar. If I copy it from the context menu it pastes as simple text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using version 4.1.0 of the [Tinymce-react integration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-react/v/4.1.0), and not version 4.1.0 of the editor, which is an older edition now.

This sounds like the Enhanced Media Embed plugin replacing your URL with a card-styled embed when you paste it.

To clarify, do you find the URL changes to the title of the page after you paste and hit the enter key? Or is it automatic?

I tested out a copy and paste of a URL [using a TinyMCE-react sandbox from a blog](https://codesandbox.io/s/tinymce-react-demo-8qfzz?from-embed=&file=/src/DocumentEditor.jsx:1755-1930) post on TinyMCE and react. Adding the Enhanced Media Embed plugin and pasting a URL created a preview URL. Turning it off, and pressing enter after pasting, kept the URL format.

I added the autolink plugin to turn the plain text URLs into a link after pasting and pressing enter.

The sandbox init:

```
init={{
            plugins: "autolink link",
            icons: "jam",
            skin: "fabric",
            content_css: "document",
            resize: false
          }}
```

Comment: The url changes immediately when I paste it, without pressing enter key.

Comment: Hi Luse, did including the autolink plugin help, or stop the URL change?

Comment: No, it didn't at all..

Comment: Ah, sorry to hear...I'll take another look at this – in the mean time, just to check could you please share the plugins you have configured in your TinyMCE init script? It might help eliminate what's causing the URL change on paste.

Comment: These are the plugins I'm using:
["lists", "image", "imagetools", "media", "emoticons", "blockquote", "paste", "table", "code", "link"]